# ubuntu 14.04 Dash default file options change?

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash

Before upgrading to 14.04 when I clicked on a file in the dash, it opened the file.

This still happens on my 12.04 machine.

In 14.04 when I click on a file in dash search results, it offers me 3 options: 'Email', 'Open' and 'Show in Folder'.

How can I get back the previous behaviour - i.e. to immediately open the files on the first click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install `dconf`:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

then run it by searching the dash for dconf, or with the command `dconf-editor`.

Navigate to `Com -> Canonical -> Unity` and change the `double-click-activate` value (untick it).

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/the-new-click-behaviour-in-the-dash).

Comment: @gevra: Instead of saying thank you, please upvote answers you found helpful. I had to learn that too ;)

Comment: He can't ... at least 15 points are required to vote.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I'm sorry! Anyway: You're welcome, @gevra :)